# VBA Compiling error 1004

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA so I apologize if the error here is obvious butI am getting a run time error in the following code and I don't understand why, My only thought is the StepCount variable being used on the first for loop gets its value assigned within the for loop itself which I cant see a way to put it before since it is based on the x being used to the for loop cycle? not sure how to link them in a way that works

```
Sub EST()

'Constants
Dim W2P As Integer
W2P = 4.2
Dim WPA As Integer
WPA = 20
Dim AKPA As Integer
AKPA = 5
Dim AKMan As Integer
AKMan = 10
Dim AKP As Integer
AKP = 4


'looping through orders
For x = 2 To 700 Step StepCount

Dim OrderNum As Integer
OrderNum = Cells(x, A).Value

'each order has sub rows loop steps unique amount each cycle
StepCount = Cells(x, BB).Value

'each order has unique number of these sub rows
Dim LineNum As Integer
LineNum = Cells(x, BA).Value

Dim Sum As Integer
Sum = 0

    'for loop supossed to perform function on each orders data
    For i = (x + 1) To (LineNum)

        Dim Ti As Integer
        Ti = 0

        Dim ItemClass As String
        ItemClass = Cells((x + 1), s).Value

        Dim QTY As Integer
        QTY = Cells((x + 1), P).Value

        Dim MAN As Integer
        MAN = Cells((x + 1), Q).Value

        Select Case ItemClass

            'Case AF

            Case AK

                If MAN = 1 Then
                    Ti = (AKP + AKMan * QTY + AKPA * QTY)
                End If

                If MAN = 0 Then
                    Ti = (AKP + AKPA * QTY)
                End If

        End Select

        Sum = Sum + Ti
       Set Cells(x, AX).Value = Sum
    Next
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: `Compile` errors and `Run Time` errors are not the same. If you add `Option Explicit` the code will tell you where your `Compile` errors are at when you try to run this

Comment: Step one in debugging: put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declare all variables. Do it once and for all by enabling "Require Variable Declarations" in the VBA editor options. In any event, I suspect that you mean `Cells(x, "A").Value` rather than `Cells(x, A).Value`.

Comment: `Step 0` is setting you up for an infinite loop, and `Integer` should probably be `Long`, except `W2P` which can't be an integer type if it needs decimals. Implicit `ActiveSheet` references are dangerous for many reasons; you'll want to qualify these `Cells` member calls with a `Worksheet` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of changes were needed to make this Compile. Adding `Option Explicit` will tell you exactly where all of your compile errors are when you try to run. Once you resolve those, you can begin to debug your run-time errors (or logic errors).

---

1) When using `Cells` you can refer to columns by Index or "Letter" (`Cells(2, 1)` or `Cells(2, "A")`)
2) You had a few variables not defined
3) No need for 2 `If` statements, just combine them by using `ElseIf`
4) You can get rid of the `Select Case` method and use both of your criteria in one `If` statement (`If MAN = 1 And ItemClass = "AK" Then`)
5) Ensure you are using the correct variables. Each variable has limitations on what it can, and cannot, hold. For instance, `Integer` cannot hold 4.2 (Your variable `WPA` would have been silently converted to 4 to match the variable you declared)
6) You need to qualify your instances of `Cells` with a worksheet.

This may still produce **run-time** errors, but it will **compile** now.

```
Option Explicit
Sub EST()

Dim WPA as Double, AKPA as Integer, AKMan as Integer, AKP As Integer
Dim W2P As Variant
W2P = 4.2
WPA = 20
AKPA = 5
AKMan = 10
AKP = 4

Dim x as Long, i as Long, StepCount As Long
Dim OrderNum, LineNum, Sum, Ti, QTY, MAN As Variant
Dim ItemClass As String

For x = 2 To 700 Step StepCount
    StepCount = Cells(x, "BB").Value
    OrderNum = Cells(x, "A").Value
    LineNum = Cells(x, "BA").Value
    Sum = 0

    For i = (x + 1) To (LineNum)
        Ti = 0
        ItemClass = Cells((x + 1), "S").Value
        QTY = Cells((x + 1), "P").Value
        MAN = Cells((x + 1), "Q").Value
            If MAN = 1 And ItemClass = "AK" Then
                Ti = (AKP + AKMan * QTY + AKPA * QTY)
            ElseIf MAN = 0 And ItemClass = "AK" Then
                Ti = (AKP + AKPA * QTY)
            End If
        Sum = Sum + Ti
        Cells(x, "AX").Value = Sum
    Next i
Next x

End Sub
```

---

1 & 2 would have been caught by `Option Explicit`
3 & 4 are more of suggestions
5 & 6 ammended from useful comments from others (Craner & Guindon)

Comment: `Dim W2P, WPA, AKPA, AKMan, AKP As Integer` only declares the last as Integer, all the others are declared variant.

Comment: ^ what he said =) ...they should probably be declared as local (?) `Const` though, if they're not reassigned anywhere.

Comment: The bit about `4.2` giving a run-time error would be true if VBA had `Option Strict` like VB.NET. Unfortunately, what happens is just a silent dropping of the decimals as the value is implicitly converted to the declared integer type.

Comment: Gotcha And thank you for the option explicit I'm use to eclipse environment so still finding all the tools in VBA and I used a select statement because there are about 10 other options I will add for item class but wanted to get the code running smoothing before adding more, thanks

Comment: That makes sense, then I would just combine the `IF` statements like above. Just remove the criteria you plan to move to `Select` (ItemClass)

Comment: _Tools ~ Options ~ Editor Tab ~ Require Variable Declaration_ to put `Option Explicit` at the top of any new modules you create.